# How to smooth an arrayed object so the breaks between objects are less obvious?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have this shape, made by arraying a single tentacle segment, using an empty scaled to 0.9 for the offset.

[image: tentacle]

I want to smooth it out, so that instead of looking like a bunch of blocks laid on top of each other, it's a smooth shape, like this:

[image: smooth tentacle]

I tried using the Smooth modifier, but it only smoothed the individual segments, even after applying all modifiers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using an empty with a scale factor, you will also need to proportionally scale one end of your mesh so it matches the scale factor given to the empty.

You can instead try an array modifier with the fit curve option, and use a bezier curve to drive it. Then use a curve modifier afterwards and control the downscaling with the curve radius by entering *Edit Mode* in the curve and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> on the tip vertex.

Don't forget to delete the top faces of your tentacle segment mesh so there are no internal faces.

The downside of this technique is that it will always give some stretching effect caused by the radius not affecting curve length.

[image]

Comment: How did you make the tentacle?

Comment: Quickly modeled it myself from a subdivided cube, nothing too fancy, as I am not much into organic modeling.

Answer (score 7):

I think if you add a shape key at the top of your mesh to scale inward. Then you will be able to "slide to fit"!

Here is the basic recipe:

1. Your Mesh.
2. A *Lattice*.
3. An Empty.
4. A *Lattice* Modifier on your Mesh.
5. An *Array* Modifier, set Object Offset to Empty.
6. Vertex Group on your mesh.
7. Vertex Group on your *Lattice*.
8. Two *Shape Keys* on your *Lattice* Object:

- One for a Basis Shape
- One for your Scaling

**Part 1 of 2**

[image: RelationshipAndModifierSetup]

**Part 2 of 2**

[image: AdjustmentProcess]