# How can I model this organic shape?

Tags: modeling

What is a good way to model this organic shape?

[image]

I've found metaballs merge too easily, so it's hard to get nice folds.

I've wondered about curves and beveling, but I haven't got good results with that either.

Comment: You may want to consider the sculpting tools. Dynotopo can be a big help here when using sculpting as well. I would recommend setting it to 6 pixels or less if you were to start with Blender's default cube. You could also do this with curves, see this [link - Duarte's answer was pretty awesome](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49651/21718)

Comment: Whatever method you use, if you want those tiny surface bubbles, you will most likely want to use the particle system after your main form.

Comment: @RickRiggs Thanks. I don't think I'll have trouble with the material; it's the foldy brain-like model that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Yeah I just looked at it again, and I'm still thinking that if you started with curves, and then converted the curve pipes to mesh, then you can sculpt and blend them together. If I can find some time I will try to break it down in an answer.