# Why aren't objects generating along this curve?

Tags: modifiers

I was trying to generate some objects along a curve, so I did all the standard process: add object, add curve, set origin of the object and the curve to same, and origin to geometry of the object and origin of 3d cursor to one point of curve and set the selected object's origin to 3d cursor, then add an array modifier.

Then I used *Object Offset* and selected the BezierCurve, but the objects aren't following along the curve and are instead in a straight line.

I don't know what's happening, can anyone help me? Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*I did all the standard process*" This is not at all the standard process. *Object Offset* is used to specify spacing between arrayed items, what you need is the *Fit Curve* option to array items to fit the length of a curve. Also an *Array* modifier is not responsible for deforming along a curve, that is the purpose of the *Curve* modifier. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier/68925#68925 or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49639/how-to-smooth-an-arrayed-object-so-the-breaks-between-objects-are-less-obvious/49651#49651

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos. Alright cool,thanks man,that worked.Learned something new :)