# How to make Curve do not deform object?

Tags: bezier-curves

I attached Array and Curve modifier to an object, there's no problem, but the Curve deforms the object as usual. So, my question is: What should i do to make Curve modifier not deform the objects?

Comment: Deforming an object is curve modifier/s job. Maybe it's not the right tool for your task. What exacty are you trying to achive?

Comment: You will be led to other question because it is absolutely unclear from yours what doesn't work for you provided the information given. For example the very first sentence in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5914/1245) (which was also mentioned by me in your previous now deleted question). Other answers on [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/how-do-i-prevent-object-distortion-when-applying-a-curve-modifier) provide useful ways to workaround that limitation.

Comment: He wants to make a tentacle where the parts follow a curve but the individual parts do not change shape. I tried duplifaces but they distort with the curve. Seems like quick fixes don't work.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49639/how-to-smooth-an-arrayed-object-so-the-breaks-between-objects-are-less-obvious and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The links in the comments are the answer but since I have made a picture, why not post it anyway:

[image]

Instead of deforming the object directly, deform a stack of tris. Then parent your target object (the cylinder in this example) to the deformed object and enable duplifaces for the tris in Properties >> Object >> Duplication.

[image]

Just make sure the object you want to duplicate has its scale applied or there will be deformations.