# Fit Object to curve length

Tags: modifiers, objects, bezier-curves

I have an Object that is using a Curve Modifier to be mapped down the length of a curve. Is there a way to make the object stretch to fit the length of the curve, even if the curve changes sizes?

Comment: what do you mean when you say that your object is mapped down the length of a curve, do you use an array?

Comment: Yes, the array modifier as a [*Fit to Curve*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49639/how-to-smooth-an-arrayed-object-so-the-breaks-between-objects-are-less-obvious/49651) option, other than that, I'm not aware of any other way. Can you post some screenshots of your usecase? Is it a simple object, a complex one? You could possibly use hooks

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos The use case is that I have a bunch of curves of different lengths, and a collection of objects that are all the same dimensions. I have a script that will assign a random object to a random curve with the Curve Modifier, and I want the objects to match the length of the curves. I'm sure there's some scripting solution, but I'm looking for other ways first.

Comment: A setting with Animation Nodes (to get the length of the curve) + a lattice around the meshes to scale + an empty that hook the lattice?

Comment: @lemon animation nodes is my next stop if there isn't already a proper way to do it, yeah. That sounds like it could work.