# How to take away the wrinkles on the tentacles?

Tags: modeling, animation

so I have just started on blender 3D modelling and have a question regarding it. Now, I'm planning to create a 3D Octopus, and I'm stuck at the tentacle's suckers. After I shade smooth the tentacles, the tentacles appear to have wrinkles, how do I solve that?

[image]

[image]

I tried Knife tool too.

Comment: please edit your question and show an image of the object in edit mode  in a way that shows the topology. Most likely you are dealing with n-gons and non planar geometry. Did you use booleans?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49639/how-to-smooth-an-arrayed-object-so-the-breaks-between-objects-are-less-obvious/49651#49651

Comment: As supected: n-gons (polygons with more than 4 vertices) creating non planar faces.. Start over and try to keep quad topology. https://topology-guides.tumblr.com/page/3

Comment: I don't think you need to start over, add a loop cut (CTRL R) between the suckers. If the problem persists, make quads from the 1. vertex that pokes into one of your ngons and the middle loop. Or add a multires and see if you can just use the smooth brush to avoid the ugly normals.

Answer (score 3):

As it has been said, your topology is bad, the stretched triangles create these artifacts. To fix this, use the knife (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through) to create new edge loops, and join (<kbd>J</kbd>) the vertices like that, and it should work:

[image]