# How to make tentacles and manipulate them easily

Tags: mesh, objects

I was wondering how I can make tentacles like this and pose/manipulate them like the shapes below, thank you!
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49639/how-to-smooth-an-arrayed-object-so-the-breaks-between-objects-are-less-obvious/49651#49651

Comment: Tentacle rigs can be difficult to implement if you want them to be easy to pose.  [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBXFJA6UdaI) is a good introduction to a good tentacle rig.

Comment: you can also look at the Spline IK solution here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116124/how-to-rig-a-cartoon-style-hose-limb-cartoon-arm