# Tentacle rig hard to control

Tags: rigging

I am creating a tentacle rig and I have found the rig I created is have it limitation.

Basically the set up I am going for is

[image]

Using 8 master bone to control multiple individual bone. This allow me to control the rig more efficiently instead of manually control 20+ small individual bone.

However, I am find it difficult to control my rig to create a particular posture. whereby the tentacle is "spiraling" up a pole. No matter how I rotate it(local/global), gap between the pole and tentacle are always created.

[image]

I am looking for a way to create a much efficient method to create the mentioned posture. A guide/video to rig that is able to complete the mentioned posture will be welcome as well.

Blender file to my rig
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using Python to control bone placement?  Do you have much experience with Python?  Have you searched for Python scripts or add-ons which do something similar?  Is the pole the only goal? Will something more complicated be the next target?

Comment: maybe the spline ik constraint is the right choice for you? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/tracking/spline_ik.html

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49639/how-to-smooth-an-arrayed-object-so-the-breaks-between-objects-are-less-obvious/

Comment: Maybe for some sequence you should use a trick, and animate with something else that an armature, like a Curve modifier on a tentacle to make it follow the spiral shape?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger unfortunately no, i dont have experience in python, was hoping it will not came to that as I have zero experience in coding. As of now the pole is the only goal, not sure in the future.

Comment: Thank you for providing suggestion "Chris, Duarte Farrajota Ramos and moonboots". I will look into it and see if it is applicable for my current problem. 

Again, thank you very much.